# Recommendations for good self-learning textbooks in group theory (or abstract algebra in general)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, self-learning, book-recommendation

I am trying to self teach myself abstract algebra and am currently looking for some good self learning books for group theory. I have already done linear algebra 1 and 2 (vector spaces, spans, bases, finite dimensions, linear transformations and homo/isomorphisms and so on). I specifically want books of the same style as Terence Tao's "Real analysis I": a lot of exposition and explaining why a topic is needed in the first place. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend Gallian's *"Contemporary Abstract Algebra"*. It has plenty of exercises, half of which come with solutions.